# How to run jar file from SVN pre-commit hook with dependencies and then pass parameter?

Tags: java, svn

I am working with pre-commit hook developed in java. Now i need to run it inside pre-commit.

- List item

How can i run jar file with dependency?
Do I have to make executable jar file to run from pre-commit?
How to give classpath and parameter to jar file?

Currntly i am ruuning in this way inside pre-commit which is working fine. Now i need to move it to production

```
 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/bin/java -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=11111 
 $JAVA_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=MacRoman 
-classpath 
 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/lib/deploy.jar:
 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/lib/dt.jar:
 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/lib/javaws.jar:
 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/lib/jce.jar:
 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:
 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/lib/management-agent.jar:
 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/lib/plugin.jar:
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:
 /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Home/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:
 /Users/testuser/Documents/Dev/projects/SCS/sc/SCS/SCS/SCSAPI/classes:
 /Users/testuser/Documents/Dev/projects/SCS/sc/g3/_lib/hibernate-tools.jar:
 /Users/testuser/Documents/Dev/projects/SCS/sc/g3/_lib/dom4j-1.4.jar:
 /Users/testuser/Documents/Dev/projects/SCS/sc/g3/_lib/commons-logging.jar:
 /Users/testuser/Documents/Dev/projects/SCS/sc/g3/_lib/commons-collections-2.1.1.jar:
 /Users/testuser/Documents/Dev/projects/SCS/sc/g3/_lib/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar:
 /Users/testuser/Documents/Dev/projects/SCS/sc/g3/_lib/hibernate2.jar:
 /Users/testuser/Documents/Dev/projects/SCS/sc/g3/_lib/ehcache-1.1.jar 
 com.ticoon.scs.SCSMain 
 pre-commit file -c /Users/testuser/Documents/Dev/projects/SCS/sc/SCS/SCS/config.xml -v -repos $REPOS -trxn $TXN
```

Answer (score 0):

**Do I have to make an executable Jar file?**

You don't need to create a runnable Jar, but that is advised because it make things easier.

Basically if you run a Jar file, you have to specify the class containing the `main()` method:

```
java -jar myjar.jar x.y.z.Main
```

If you have a `Main-Class: x.y.z.Main` attribute defined in your `MANIFEST.MF` file, you can run the Jar file by simply:

```
java -jar myjar.jar
```

**How to give classpath to a Jar file?**

When you run something with the `java -jar ...` command, the `-classpath ...` property is dropped. The reason is security (Jar files can be digitally signed to ensure they weren't modified and it would be so easy to make java load a different dependency Jar file with the same content but with hijacked functionality).

The solution is simple: include the `Class-Path: ...` attribute too in your `MANIFEST.MF` file as you do with `Main-Class: ...`.

**How to give parameters to a Jar file?**

As you would give parameters to a simple Java program (and the [manual specifies](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html) it):

```
java -jar myjar.jar arg1 arg2 ... argN
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  i am now working on making classpath inside MANIFEST.MF lets see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Yehh its working now with single file. thanks @rlegendi 
Working copy

```
 REPOS="$1"
 TXN="$2"
 java -jar /Users/testuser/Documents/SCS/SCS.jar pre-commit file -c /Users/testuser/Documents/SCSAPI/config.xml -repos $REPOS -trxn $TXN
```